# How do I pin bodies using the Magneto-stick in TTT?

Tags: garrys-mod, trouble-in-terrorist-town

How do I hang a body using the Magneto-stick in Trouble in terrorist town? 
I have yet to find instruction on how to. 
I have checked the lua file for the stick, as well as Steam's forums and guides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on a body and then left click on a wall to pin it, but the server needs `ttt_ragdoll_pinning` set to 1 and you need to be a traitor or have `ttt_ragdoll_pinning_innocents` set to 1

Comment: More info. Thanks! I know what to tell my friend to change now.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the body to pick it up and then click on the wall or ceiling where you wish to place them.

I wish i could give you more info but it is simple